# Get different builds for logo in assets folder in Angular8

Tags: html, angular, package.json

There is a *logo.jpeg* with the same name for 2 cities in asset folder. And when I say build: london, I want the london logo to come on the project. I do not want to give like that "img source in assets / london / logo.jpeg or assets / paris / logo.jpeg". my build: city should come according to the city's logo

app.component.html

```
<div class="condition1">
  <img src="/assets/logo.jpeg">
</div>
```

angular.json

```
"root": "",
"sourceRoot": "src",
"prefix": "app",
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
      "outputPath": "dist",
      "index": "src/index.html",
      "main": "src/main.ts",
      "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
      "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "aot": false,
      "styles": [
      ],
      "scripts": []
    },
    "configurations": {
      "london": {
        "assets": [
          { "glob": "*.jpeg", "input": "src/assets/paris", "output": "assets"}
        ],
        "fileReplacements": [
          {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
          }
        ], "optimization": true,
        "outputHashing": "all",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "extractCss": true,
        "namedChunks": false,
        "aot": true,
        "extractLicenses": true,
        "vendorChunk": false,
        "buildOptimizer": true,
        "budgets": [
          {
            "type": "initial",
            "maximumWarning": "2mb",
            "maximumError": "5mb"
          },
          {
            "type": "anyComponentStyle",
            "maximumWarning": "6kb",
            "maximumError": "10kb"
          }
        ]},
      "paris": {
        "assets": [
          { "glob": "*.jpeg", "input": "/src/assets/paris/", "output": "assets"}
        ],
        "fileReplacements": [
          {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
          }
        ],
        "optimization": true,
        "outputHashing": "all",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "extractCss": true,
        "namedChunks": false,
        "aot": true,
        "extractLicenses": true,
        "vendorChunk": false,
        "buildOptimizer": true,
        "budgets": [
          {
            "type": "initial",
            "maximumWarning": "2mb",
            "maximumError": "5mb"
          },
          {
            "type": "anyComponentStyle",
            "maximumWarning": "6kb",
            "maximumError": "10kb"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same approach that [this article](https://yakovfain.com/2017/04/06/angular-cli-multiple-apps-in-the-same-project/) describes.
For example, you can have an assets folder for each city, and then you can define an app for each city where the only difference is the assets folder they use.